# Big-Oh notation calculating constant steps

Tags: java, big-o

I've searched about Big O notation for some time, and I learned that when calculating we have to assume that every sentence that doesn't depend on the size of the input data takes a constant C number computational steps.

My program goes like this. 
It "always" takes in a "48 bit" random seed and produces an output, and the actual moves that happen within the process of producing the output varies according to the seed value itself, not by the size because it's fixed.
I for looped this process for n times, in order to get n outputs.

Does this mean the Big O notation is O(n) for my program? Or am I completely misunderstanding something?

So, the number of loops I just write in the code. For example, if I set it to 1000, it takes in 1000 input seeds and produces 1000 outputs. The process within the loop, so the number of for loops or the number of if - else or switch statements inside the bigger loop are fixed. The only thing that changes inside the bigger loop is which "if statement" to choose depending on the value of the seed.

Comment: Please clarify how the number of loops varies with the input/seed

Comment: If `n` is known beforehand and doesn't depend on input in any way then it is O(1) (constant time/complexity).

Comment: @Ivan by that argument, *any* computer program is `O(1)` since computers don't have infinite memory, so the maximum number of bits in the input is the memory that the computer has. If the *algorithm* (which depends on the *value* n, not "48 bits") can be described for an n as it approaches infinity, then the complexity of the algorithm can be determined, even if the particular implementation on a computer limits n to 2^48-1.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, I mean if that program uses let's say array of 48 bits and then iterates over it 10 times (if n = 10) why isn't it O(1)? I mean if `n` is declared like `static final int n =10` (or any other constant) in the code.

Comment: So, the number of loops I just write in the code. For example, if I set it to 1000, it takes in 1000 input seeds and produces 1000 outputs. The process within the loop, so the number of for loops or the number of if - else or switch statements inside the bigger loop are fixed. The only thing that changes inside the bigger loop is which "if statement" to choose depending on the value of the seed.

Comment: @Ivan The OP wrote "varies according to the seed value itself, not by the size because it's fixed". So n is a value from 0 to 2^48-1 in his implementation, not a constant. But if his algorithm can be described for any n, then you can determine the complexity of the algorithm regardless of the implementation limit. Any computer program has an implementation limit, since memory is not infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity is always expressed as relative to *something*.

Since your input length is constant, it doesn't make much sense to express the complexity relative to that. It may have *O(n)* complexity relative to number of loops, but again, since the value is hard-coded this information will have little value to the user.

Perhaps the most useful in your case is information about what the complexity is relative to the input *value*. If that is constant, you can say that your program performs in *constant time*, because no matter what the (valid) user input will be, the time it will take your program to produce the output will roughly be the same.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm a beginner, and I want to express the performance speed of my program to check if it's fast or not, and the first thing that came up in my mind was the Big - O notation. If Big - O notation has little value in this case, is there another effective way of calculating the performance speed? Thanks again.

Comment: Big-O complexity is only useful if you're worried that a slightly larger input might lead to catastrophically low performance. For expressing performance of a small, input-independent, performance-critical part, you would probably count number of operations performed per run - e.g. 5 steps, then loop another 3 operations 1000 times, then 1 or 3 steps depending on condition afterwards = 3009 operations (including worst-case, including condition evaluation).

Comment: Also keep in mind that I/O operations are typically much more expensive (i.e. take much longer time) than in-memory operations, so if the program uses any I/O it might make sense to only count I/O operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
int f(int[] a, int[] b, int c) {
    int n = a.length;
    int m = b.length;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        y += a[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            y -= b[j];
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < c; ++k) {
        y += 13;
    }
    return y;
}
```

So the complexity is `O(n.m)+O(c)` counting steps (loop, recursive calls).

```
    for (long k = seed; k > 1; k /= 2) {
        ...;
    }
```

would give `O(²log seed)`, at most 48.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly said, O(n) means that this n is algorithm parameter/input of some kind or derived from it. It can be length of input, or even output, but it's derived from algorithm parameter.

So, this O(n) has a meaning when we talk about your procedure "loop this process for n times", if you automated this procedure with some script. Algorithm itself still works in O(1) time. If you don't automate procedure, just forget about Big O - manual action makes it irrelevant.